# Enabling Hadoop Namenode HA in Apache ambari using Bigtop

Tags: hadoop, ambari, bigtop

I Cloned the Bigtop code from Github, built RPMS, and installed the Hadoop cluster using Ambari. The Hadoop cluster had 3 nodes. When the name node HA is enabled from Ambari, the services do not start in step 7( Start Components  ), so forward steps cannot be performed. Ambari agent throws some errors when it comes to step 7.

```
> Ambari-2.7.5
> Hadoop-3.3.4
> Zookeeper-3.5.9
> Linux server: Centos-7
```

In Ambari agent i am getting the following the error in the log.

```
> INFO 2022-12-05 13:58:37,440 __init__.py:82 - Event from server at /user/ (correlation_id=227): {u'status': u'OK'}
> ERROR 2022-12-05 13:58:37,704 alert_ha_namenode_health.py:185 - [Alert] NameNode High Availability Health on instance-5 fails:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/alerts/alert_ha_namenode_health.py", line 175, in execute
> state_response = get_jmx(jmx_uri, connection_timeout)
> File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/alerts/alert_ha_namenode_health.py", line 206, in get_jmx
> response = urllib2.urlopen(query, timeout=connection_timeout)
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
> return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
> response = self._open(req, data)
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
>     '_open', req)
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
> result = func(*args)
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1244, in http_open
> return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in do_open
> raise URLError(err)
> URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

[Ambari UI While trying to Enable HA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiO7r.png)

**Namenode Log**

```
> 2022-12-08 07:12:52,477 INFO  namenode.FSEditLog
> (FSEditLog.java:printStatistics(794)) - Number of transactions: 168
> Total time for transactions(ms): 19 Number of transactions batched in
> Syncs: 4638 Number of syncs: 143 SyncTimes(ms): 268 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,481 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/38b9c9dc549394c67f819f03f02ef67c/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,481 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/54a35f5c02b78671aa3cb1a555d4f13d/recovered.edits/22.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,486 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/TEST_MERGE_SPLIT/65daedd407be5de5db0a6df509451aac/recovered.edits/25.seqid is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,489 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.STATS/2b8248a14c2e38b71595200ae6cb6e9c/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,489 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/90de5ae3b5daaf334553cb73d3cffe96/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,495 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/8d944f63f2eec5d95fbf16a45eda13d1/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,496 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/hbase/meta/1588230740/recovered.edits/1300.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,526 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/611f59084c88307ee011a520a00cf1eb/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,529 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/5dbe5b39d39be33e7c549caab73352ba/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,530 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/ba0d8e224fd563575687aab2afa1de39/recovered.edits/25.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,534 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/2760ea047005151d035b988ef5a526f5/recovered.edits/22.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,536 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/TEST_MERGE_SPLIT/f8129cf7b0102dabf7ec9683513c1feb/recovered.edits/25.seqid is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,566 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.TASK/8667cc4454dd118504027c07ed8c150f/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,567 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/a023890792b51c1551471baaf3f385f5/recovered.edits/25.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,567 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/67a1e7ae67d76782a2adbaae3b2687a9/recovered.edits/25.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,582 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/TEST_MERGE_SPLIT/b59bdfcad8908003169571d01f135278/recovered.edits/22.seqid is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,583 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/4c62db7bf1c479ede323e53d21d9a41f/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,583 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/3ea53d95ec4227d5f5fc24c5e79a801f/recovered.edits/22.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,583 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/4604f896ccf933960a21a4f81edfa23f/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,584 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/f0030813232204d5165972d0b99e4a82/recovered.edits/25.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,586 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/0533eb20acb1aa3233403c30dcff05a6/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,612 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/303cb7d7b8ce11cbc4df9bc83e122898/recovered.edits/22.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,615 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/7a766993e99daeb64e3d2219ca8c9427/recovered.edits/22.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,616 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/4a3abf63944203c5020a3f2ef5749c44/recovered.edits/22.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,629 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/6be9c041387ca418f6c35f91135a3b7e/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,629 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/210c8496760d4754384b27bf3b45c072/recovered.edits/25.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,655 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/TEST_MERGE_SPLIT/df5d0ccbe8941453697c89984985ecd1/recovered.edits/22.seqid is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,655 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.CATALOG/ee1348d962c03994578d6bc8f0389831/recovered.edits/43.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,655 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/afa9666d2296f1d7c8629bbc7fc84073/recovered.edits/22.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,662 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/52b00f10bbcede600fe5f434b34629e9/recovered.edits/22.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,665 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/TEST_MERGE_SPLIT/a3fa94f77440b13d37602dace771aa7d/recovered.edits/29.seqid is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,678 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/TEST_MERGE_SPLIT/6c02cf70d5286b712c89a5f136167476/recovered.edits/26.seqid is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,679 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/526cacd3866c13e1c229baa123108783/recovered.edits/22.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,683 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.SEQUENCE/9db3f45bdef2439677f1d7cfed837e24/recovered.edits/25.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,705 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/TEST_MERGE_SPLIT/498c428ad17956df4843f78642957840/recovered.edits/23.seqid is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,706 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/hbase/namespace/bb7e9d3268a1cdf39f49426f0014cf37/recovered.edits/33.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,708 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.MUTEX/c7ec76e62616a4da4f8b81230921dd78/recovered.edits/22.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,709 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/TEST_MERGE_SPLIT/6f89e061764c1ec1a64b608e6e18c62c/recovered.edits/22.seqid is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,710 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.FUNCTION/85740d4c80415117ddf7c8321cabd250/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,714 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/TEST_MERGE_SPLIT/a26508adf2909c8bca5c4f02985bb096/recovered.edits/25.seqid is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,725 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/049bc3d9d7d676e72af6e31163db4364/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,725 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/c96562dd2509624dfe49f1586652e083/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,726 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/65b3fbf36173133b8b368e7fa7b37306/recovered.edits/22.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,727 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/58986e109c517c6893f00bd9c749144a/recovered.edits/22.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,730 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/11de2f3f2cc497467a17e3ba7a32c50a/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,733 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/a39782166928fc109f1c752a47b59ed1/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,750 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/17caf4e0a9ed1bb532569a413f59abe1/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,753 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/TEST_MERGE_SPLIT/1841e792cdbfa7f1f4536da504c68560/recovered.edits/22.seqid is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,753 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/3783addc127d101a5843032326989852/recovered.edits/19.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,772 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.LOG/f092c53f69188d676108ab1dc970629b/recovered.edits/22.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,774 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/TEST_MERGE_SPLIT/a53c806891e4e8573000bb3deb31895e/recovered.edits/25.seqid is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,776 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/data/default/SYSTEM.CHILD_LINK/78e4a7a00c64a00f1839d32d1a6d61d6/recovered.edits/25.seqid
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,874 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/WALs/ambari-agent-02.ambari,16020,1670481872455/ambari-agent-02.ambari%2C16020%2C1670481872455.1670481890182
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1334295705_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,877 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/WALs/ambari-agent-03.ambari,16020,1670481872397/ambari-agent-03.ambari%2C16020%2C1670481872397.meta.1670481887307.meta
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,898 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/WALs/ambari-agent-03.ambari,16020,1670481872397/ambari-agent-03.ambari%2C16020%2C1670481872397.1670481889996
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-62228341_1 2022-12-08
> 07:12:52,913 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(2979)) - DIR* completeFile:
> /apps/hbase/data/WALs/ambari-agent-01.ambari,16020,1670481873184/ambari-agent-01.ambari%2C16020%2C1670481873184.1670481890944
> is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1463686342_1 2022-12-08
> 07:15:43,548 INFO  namenode.FSEditLog
> (FSEditLog.java:printStatistics(794)) - Number of transactions: 344
> Total time for transactions(ms): 32 Number of transactions batched in
> Syncs: 4690 Number of syncs: 268 SyncTimes(ms): 423 2022-12-08
> 07:15:43,548 INFO  hdfs.StateChange
> (FSNamesystem.java:enterSafeMode(4721)) - STATE* Safe mode is ON. It
> was turned on manually. Use "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" to turn
> safe mode off. 2022-12-08 07:16:03,457 INFO  namenode.FSImage
> (FSImage.java:saveNamespace(1146)) - Save namespace ... 2022-12-08
> 07:16:03,458 INFO  namenode.FSEditLog
> (FSEditLog.java:endCurrentLogSegment(1426)) - Ending log segment 4614,
> 4957 2022-12-08 07:16:03,459 INFO  namenode.FSEditLog
> (FSEditLog.java:printStatistics(794)) - Number of transactions: 345
> Total time for transactions(ms): 32 Number of transactions batched in
> Syncs: 4690 Number of syncs: 269 SyncTimes(ms): 425 2022-12-08
> 07:16:03,462 INFO  namenode.FileJournalManager
> (FileJournalManager.java:finalizeLogSegment(145)) - Finalizing edits
> file
> /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_inprogress_0000000000000004614 ->
> /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000000000004614-0000000000000004958
> 2022-12-08 07:16:03,489 INFO  namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf
> (FSImageFormatProtobuf.java:save(511)) - Saving image file
> /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000004958 using
> no compression 2022-12-08 07:16:03,566 INFO 
> namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf (FSImageFormatProtobuf.java:save(515))
> - Image file /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000004958 of size
> 43959 bytes saved in 0 seconds . 2022-12-08 07:16:03,572 INFO 
> namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager
> (NNStorageRetentionManager.java:getImageTxIdToRetain(203)) - Going to
> retain 2 images with txid >= 1160 2022-12-08 07:16:03,572 INFO 
> namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager
> (NNStorageRetentionManager.java:purgeImage(226)) - Purging old image
> FSImageFile(file=/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/fsimage_0000000000000000000,
> cpktTxId=0000000000000000000) 2022-12-08 07:16:03,582 INFO 
> namenode.FSEditLog (FSEditLog.java:startLogSegment(1381)) - Starting
> log segment at 4959 2022-12-08 07:16:03,593 INFO 
> namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:saveNamespace(4547)) - New
> namespace image has been created 2022-12-08 07:16:53,274 ERROR
> namenode.NameNode (LogAdapter.java:error(75)) - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15:
> SIGTERM 2022-12-08 07:16:53,278 INFO  namenode.FSImage
> (FSImage.java:lambda$run$0(1053)) - FSImageSaver clean checkpoint:
> txid=4958 when meet shutdown. 2022-12-08 07:16:53,278 INFO 
> namenode.NameNode (LogAdapter.java:info(51)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:
> /************************************************************
> SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ambari-server/172.20.0.2
> ************************************************************/
```

**While executing sudo su hdfs -l -c 'hdfs namenode -initializeSharedEdits' command below log is printing**

[Command Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUP30.png)

Comment: You need to give namenode server logs. Ambari is stuck trying to connect to a failing server

Comment: I will upload the namenode server logs

Comment: I see that you are using ip addresses.  (or at least this is mentioned in the shutdown message) This can cause issues for server communication.  Are you using IP addresses or hostnames/domain names ?

Comment: I am using the hostnames which already registered in the ambari